# mmWormHole Library and appGroupContainerPath variable always returns nil

Tags: objective-c, mmwormhole

I'm testing the library and I have a problem with `messagePassingDirectoryPath`. 
When I generate a message it's work correctly, but when I'm listening I have this issue:

I use `listenForMessageWithIdentifier` function to listen for messages and when in the library flow reaches `messagePassingDirectoryPath` function line:

```
NSURL *appGroupContainer = [self.fileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:self.applicationGroupIdentifier];
```

It always returns a null value.

the `self.applicationGroupIdentifier` variable has the correct value with my group.

If I set `NSString *directoryPath = appGroupContainerPath;` to a string with my actual path, something like `(@"/Users/gero/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FA4C68DD-4F63-42B3-89A5-6C611A298199/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/B049FE4D-EE9F-44E3-AE2A-897C05447471/wormhole/)` it works, and I receive messages correctly.

Do you know if it's an issue or I need configure something?